# IIS can't run queries?

Tags: sql-server

I've an odd problem.

I remote desktop to a Windows 2012 machine using a domain account, and in Internet Explorer go to a website (which is ASP classic) hosted by IIS on the machine I've logged into. That website connects to a database, hosted on some other machine, successfully, and logs in. But it fails to run a select query (I get an error that the connection has to be re-established). Note that the account I make the remote desktop connction with is not the same account which the application pool is run as. Also, the ASP classic website makes the SQL Server connection using SQL auth and not by domain account login.

I close that remote desktop session, then connect to the same machine with using the domain account which IIS is run as. This time there are no issues running the same SQL query.

How can my Windows auth affect whether the query runs successfully or not?

I then setup a copy of the website on a Windows 2008 machine, and host its database on some other machine (not mentioned previously). I configure both websites the same (except for DB hostnames). I remote desktop to this IIS host using a domain account which doesn't match the one that runs IIS, but this website works without error when I open it in IE.

Is it possible that Windows 2021 (and not 2008) is forcing an SQL connection using a domain account despite the website attempting to log in using SQL Auth?

Comment: "Is it possible that Windows 2021 (and not 2008) is forcing an SQL connection using a domain account despite the website attempting to log in using SQL Auth?" No, that is not possible.

Comment: It sounds like your have an authentication configuration problem in either the site or its application pool. Probably best asked on [dba.stackexchange.com/](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If the SqlConnection is using SQL Login authentication then, from an SQL Server point of view, it doesn't matter which account the Application Pool is configured to use nor which account you access the web page with because Windows auth isn't being used on the SqlConnection. It seems likely that like the ASP.net web page itself is using custom impersonation code, maybe for other purposes like logging, and just isn't doing it correctly.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Except I wrote the ASP page (it's ASP classic, not .NET). Yes, it's a very old legacy site.